# Como criar um link fixo no wordpress?

Tags: html, wordpress, link, wordpress-theme

Galera estou implementando um site em html estático para wordpress, não são todas as paginas que precisam do cms para gerenciar o conteudo, meu problema é o seguinte!

Não consigo criar um link do Menu para uma página estática ou uma pagina qualquer
Wordpress 4

exemplo

```
<a href="contato.php">contato</a>
Simplesmente ele não consegue encontrar a página contato.php
```

no melhor dos mundos isso devia funcionar pois já tentei pois estão todos nos mesmos diretórios, já vi no codex que o wordpress funciona diferente mas já tentei várias soluções e nada, alguém pode dar um help.

Comment: Qual menu? Em `http://seu-site/wp-admin/nav-menus.php`? Se colocar `http://seu-site/caminho/contato.php` não funciona?

Comment: Você não falou sobre a versão do Wordpress, porém esse plugin deve resolver o seu problema:
[Wordpress Page Links To](https://wordpress.org/plugins/page-links-to/)

Comment: Você quer linkar para uma página ou um link externo?

Comment: @GabrielTadraMainginski manjo pouco de wordpress vi o plugin mas nao sei se e disso que preciso

Comment: @GiulianoGriffante e para uma pagina interna.

Comment: @brasofilo e um menu do proprio site que estou passando para wordpress e preciso criar uma chamda so para ele funcionar corretamente?

Comment: Helton, não sei o que é uma "chamda so"... (?) . . . Pode [edit] a pergunta para esclarecer? Não está nada claro qual sua configuração.

Comment: @brasofilo e um menu do proprio site que estou passando para wordpress e preciso apenas criar os links com as outras paginas.

Comment: É... não consigo entender, sorry...

Comment: @brasofilo Sem problema valeu...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depois de criado a página no admistrativo do wordpress no atributo href você deve colocar o caminho da seguinte forma

```
<a href="<?php bloginfo('url')?>/nomeDaPagina">Link da pagina</a>
```

Answer (score 3):

Pelo link que você colocou, parece que o contato.php está como um *link relativo*. Isso quer dizer que o navegador vai procurar a página dependendo do caminho atual que você está navegando.

Exemplo, se você está em seusite.com.br/categoria/artigo/
O link acima vai  ser seusite.com.br/categoria/artigo/contato.php

Se você está em seusite.com.br/sobre/
O link vai ser: seusite.com.br/sobre/contato.php

Então, basta você colocar o caminho completo para o seu contato.php. Por exemplo, se você colocou o arquivo dentro do raiz do domínio, o link fica:

```
<a href="/contato.php">contato</a>
```

(Também, no seu post original, você fechou a tag com </p> ao invés de </a>)

Então, verifique exatamente o local onde a página que você quer linkar está (via navegador mesmo) e use o link relativo corretamente.